# Import/Export of Panelized Nodes

Tags: 7, nodes, importing-exporting, panels

I'm using [Panelizer](https://drupal.org/project/panelizer) to *panelize* nodes of a specific content. This content type is used so that content editors on the website can easily edit (with the help of Panels IPE) the content of pages which all have unique custom layouts (ie. different sets of panels panes at different positions).

To ease deployments, I"m looking for a way export *panelized* nodes from the development (local) site to the validation and production sites in a non-interactive fashion. Import/Export of nodes themselves is not the issue here, there is several solutions. But, AFAIK, none of them handle the panelizer part. The solutions to use will likely depend on the exact how to export/import the panelizer part of the *panelized* nodes and how it can be integrated in an automated workflow.

So far, for a *panelized* `$node`, I've found the following

```
// Export the panelized entity information
ctools_export_crud_export('panelizer_entity', $node->panelizer['page_manager']);
// Export the panel display of the entity
ctools_export_crud_export('panels_diplay', $node->panelizer['page_manager']->display);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using [uuid_features](https://www.drupal.org/project/uuid_features) the dev version (dev+36)
 and you may need Panelizer (dev) there are some patches there that will solve problems for you.

Also you can try [deploy](https://www.drupal.org/project/deploy) module, though I didn't use it, but it looks like it will become a more promising solution.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Panel contents, you may be able to use Node Export and Features modules. With this, I'm able to export the fully configured and populated Panelizer node.

However, I'm running into a problem where, if I've added an existing node, the NID isn't being translated to the new NID.

If you are just exporting a Panelizer node with panes to fields, or views, etc., i.e. something where the machine ID is the same on all servers, this should work very well.

Make sure to configure your Node Export Features settings the same way on all servers.

Additionally, you should use the XML export option or PHP serialize (if that works for you). See this thread for issues with Panelizer exports: https://www.drupal.org/node/1304942 and https://www.drupal.org/node/1916524